# How to implement getCountryCode to getPhoneNumber

Tags: java, string-formatting

Here is code in java but. How can i implement `getCountryCode` method to `getPhoneNumber`  which is 38 for example

```
public String getPhoneNumber()
 {
    System.out.println(String.format("+%d(%2$s)%3$s-%4$s-%5$s", 38,
    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(0, 3), 
    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(3, 6),
    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(6, 8), 
    String.format("%010d", 501234567).substring(8)));
    }
```

here is what i get when im trying to replace 38 with getCountryCode

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2748)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2702)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2797)
    at com.javarush.test.level19.lesson03.task03.Solution$IncomeDataAdapter.getPhoneNumber(Solution.java:100)
    at com.javarush.test.level19.lesson03.task03.Solution.main(Solution.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Look into `String.format(..)`. Also, don't expect us to do the work for you. Show us some effort.

Comment: C# and Java are different.

Comment: Your question is too broad ....

Comment: Replace `38` with `getCountryCode()`, ...? Should you return the string, not print it though? And shouldn't you pass an integer to the function? Or are you just doing things one step at a time?

Comment: if you are printing in the method why do you have a String return type? obvious error

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    getPhoneNumber();
}

private static String countryCode = "0058";
private static String number = "0123456789";

public static void getPhoneNumber()
{
    System.out.println(
         String.format("%s (%s)%s-%s-%s", 
              getCountryCode(), 
              number.substring(0,4),
              number.substring(4,6), 
              number.substring(6,8), 
              number.substring(8,10)));
}

public static String getCountryCode()
{
    return countryCode;
}
```

Very simple solution

Comment: i dont know, its doesnt put country code in front of ()             String fullNumber = incomeData.getCountryCode() + " (";

Comment: this is what i get, (0123)45-678-89